# right to left dialog in mahapps

Tags: wpf, dialog, right-to-left, mahapps.metro

I'm using Mahapps,metro toolkit for create a WPF application.I want to show a right to left dialog.

```
await this.ShowMessageAsync("This is the title", "Some message");
```

I am usig above code to create dialog but it is left to right.

Comment: When you say "right to left dialog" what exactly do you mean? Do you want the text fixed to the right side of the dialog box? Do you want the characters to appear in backwards order such as "eltit eht si sihT"?

Comment: I want the text fixed to the right side

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.just add this style to app.xaml

`<Style TargetType="{x:Type Dialog:MessageDialog}"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Dialog:BaseMetroDialog}}">
    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft" />
</Style>`

Here is my app.xaml file

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RandomQuestions"
         xmlns:Dialogs="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Dialogs:MessageDialog}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Dialogs:BaseMetroDialog}}">
            <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft" />
        </Style>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Amber.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to align right in a MessageBox. You should check to see if there is a similar way to do this using MahApps.Metro:

```
MessageBox.Show("hi", "hey", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information, MessageBoxResult.OK, MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
```

The parameters, in order, are:

- Message
- Title
- Button type
- Icon displayed
- Button type that is returned by user click
- **Display options** (this is the parameter you are looking for)

This creates the following dialog box:

[image]

Comment: There is not a similar way to do this using Mahapps.Metro.I guess I should create a CustomResourceDictionary, but I don't know how :(

Comment: `ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary();`

then you can set properties on rd
then add rd to be the CustomResourceDictionary